# Why doesn’t crontab execute well my script

Tags: mysql, macos, cron

I wrote a script that I want to execute every minute

I wanna save my database every minute.

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASS="root"
DB_HOST="localhost"

OUTDIR=`date +%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M:%S`

mkdir -p /Users/mess/backup_DB/$OUTDIR

DATABASES=`MYSQL_PWD=$DB_PASS mysql -u $DB_USER -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v -e Database -e _schema -e mysql`

for DB_NAME in $DATABASES; do
    MYSQL_PWD=$DB_PASS mysqldump -u $DB_USER --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables $DB_NAME -h $DB_HOST > /Users/mess/backup_DB/$OUTDIR/$DB_NAME.sql
done

for DB_NAME in $DATABASES; do
    gzip /Users/mess/backup_DB/$OUTDIR/$DB_NAME.sql
done
```

When I execute my script it’s work but when I use cron to execute it automatically it’s doesn’t work, crontab create the folder but not the file (database.sql.zip)

Here my cron :

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/Users/mess/scripts/bin

 * * * * * backup
```

Comment: Do you really want to run this every minute?

Comment: No every Friday but I tried every minute and it doesn’t work